# Счетчик отправленных форм на php/валидация формы/подключение reCAPTCHA

Tags: javascript, php, css, html5, form

Я пытаюсь реализовать счетчик отправки формы на php, если данные с формы отправляются на сервер, в файл counter.txt записывается +1, потом эти данные используются для формирования заголовка в письме как № заявки. 
Все работает, но на почту приходит 12 одинаковых писем, при следующей отправке 32 и тд. В чем проблема? Почему это происходит?

```
  <?php


$email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['f']['sel']));
$change = trim(strip_tags($_POST['f']['button-set']));
$name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['f']['name']));
$question = trim(strip_tags($_POST['f']['message']));
$submit = trim(strip_tags($_POST['f']['submit'])); 

if(isset($submit)){
    $count = file_get_contents('counter.txt'); 
    $count++;
    file_put_contents('counter.txt',$count); 
}
else {
    $count = file_get_contents('counter.txt');
};

$to = 'support@archsupport.ru'; 
$subject = 'Заявка №:' . $count . ' с сайта archsupport.ru'; 
$message = 'Имя: ' . $name . "\r\n" . 'Контакты: ' . $email . "\r\n" . 'Написать ' . $change . "\r\n" . 'Вопрос: ' . $question  ; 
$headers = 'From: zergg52@gmail.com ' . "\r\n";
$subject = preg_replace("/(\r\n)|(\r)|(\n)/", "", $subject);
$subject = preg_replace("/(\t)/", " ", $subject);
$subject = '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=';
@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo 'сообщение отправлено!';

?>
```

Код страницы:

```js
var form  = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
var names = document.getElementById('name');
var validn = document.getElementById('vn');
var iconrequired = document.querySelector('#namereq');
var email = document.getElementById('sellection');
var valids = document.getElementById('vs');
var iconrequireds = document.querySelector('#sellectionreq');
var text = document.getElementById('qestions');
var validt = document.getElementById('vt');
var iconrequiredt = document.querySelector('#textreq');


document.addEventListener('input', function validation() {

 var x = document.forms["support"]["sellection"].value;


  if (names.validity.valid) {
    validn.className = "valid";
  iconrequired.className = "iconrequired hide";
 
  };
 
 if (email.validity.valid && x != "") {

   valids.className = "valid";
  iconrequireds.className = "iconrequired hide";

  };
 if (text.validity.valid) {
   validt.className = "valid";
   iconrequiredt.className = "iconrequired hide";
  
  };
 if (!names.validity.valid) {
 validn.className = "invalid";
  iconrequired.className = "iconrequired hide";
 
  };
  if (!email.validity.valid) {
   valids.className = "invalid";
  iconrequireds.className = "iconrequired hide";
  
  };
  
  if (!text.validity.valid){
   validt.className = "invalid";
  iconrequiredt.className = "iconrequired hide";

  }; 
  
if (names.validity.valid && email.validity.valid && text.validity.valid){ 

  $('#support').submit(function(){
      
    $.post(
        'https://www.archsupport.ru/post-email.php', // адрес обработчика
         $("#support").serialize(), // отправляемые данные          
  
        function(msg) { // получен ответ сервера  
            $('#support').hide('slow');
            $('#my_message_email').html(msg);
        }
    );
    
    
});

 
  } else {
  
  return false;
  
  }
});





  function validateSellection(){
var x=document.forms["support"]["sellection"].value;
if (x === "") {
document.getElementById('sellectionreq').classList.remove("hide");
return false;
} else {
document.getElementById('sellectionreq').classList.add("hide");
return false;
}
};
 function validateName(){
var x=document.forms["support"]["name"].value;
if (x === "") {
document.getElementById('namereq').classList.remove("hide");
return false;
} else {
document.getElementById('namereq').classList.add("hide");
return false;
}
};

 function validateText(){
var x=document.forms["support"]["qestions"].value;
if (x === "") {
document.getElementById('textreq').classList.remove("hide");
return false;
} else {
document.getElementById('textreq').classList.add("hide");
return false;
}
};

$('#support').submit(function validate(){
if(validateName() && validateSellection() && validateText()===true){

return ;
} else {

validateSellection();
validateName();
validateText()
return false

}
});



$(".radio").on('click.two', function() {
      let input = $("#sellection");
      if ($("#radio").prop("checked")) {
        input.prop("disabled", false);
        input.prop({
    "type": "email",
          "placeholder": "example@yourmail.ru",
          "autocomplete": "email",
          "maxlength": "35",
          "minlength": "12",
     "value": "",
        });
        document.getElementById("sellection").pattern = "^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$";
      } else {
        input.prop("disabled", false);
        $("#sellection").prop({
    "type": "tel",
          "placeholder": "+7-910-205-46-15",
          "autocomplete": "tel",
          "maxlength": "16",
          "minlength": "11",
     "value": "",
        });
        document.getElementById("sellection").pattern = "\\+7\\s?[\\(]{0,1}9[0-9]{2}[\\)]{0,1}\\s?\\d{3}[-]{0,1}\\d{2}[-]{0,1}\\d{2}";
      }
      input.focus();
      input.val("");
    });
    
var iconsel = $('.icons');
iconsel.on('click.ten', function iconback() {
 iconsel.removeClass('checked');
  $(this).addClass('checked');
});
```

```css
  @font-face {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr-Thin";
  src: url("/fonts/HelveticaNeueCyr-Thin.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-display: swap;
   }

@keyframes req { 0% { transform:translatex(0px)    ; } 100% { transform:translatex(5px)   ; } }
 
 @keyframes inv { 0% { opacity:.5   ; } 100% { opacity:1    ; } }

* {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}


:root {
 font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr-Thin";
 font-weight:100;
}
 form {
   font-size: 24px;
   position: relative;
   width:100%;
   display: inline-flex;
   flex-direction: column;
 }

 


 textarea {
   height: 30vh;
   border-radius: 18px;
   padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top:10px;
   border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
   overflow: hidden;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   outline: none;
   resize: none
 }

 input,
 textarea {
   font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr-Thin";
   font-weight: 100;
   font-size: 18px;
 }

 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: gray;
   font-size: 18px;
 }

 ::-moz-placeholder {
   color: gray;
   font-size: 18px;
 }

 /* Firefox 19+ */
 :-moz-placeholder {
   color: gray;
   font-size: 18px;
 }

 /* Firefox 18- */
 :-ms-input-placeholder {
   color: gray;
   font-size: 18px;
 }
input:not([type="submit"]) {
  border-radius:100px;
 padding-left:15px;
  height:36px;
 border:none;
 background: #f3f3f3;
 }
 
 input:focus {
  outline:none;
  border:2px solid #f3f3f3;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 background:white;
 padding-left:13px;
 
 }

 .required {
  display:inline-flex;
 width:100%;
 flex-direction: column;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 position:relative;
 }
 .iconrequired{
  margin:auto;
  display:flex;
 align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width:90px;
 height:14px;
 color: white;
 border-radius:100px;
  font-size:10px;
 font-weight:100;
 font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr-Thin";
 background:#343434;
 position:absolute;
 right:15px;
 top: 10px;
 opacity:1;
 transition: opacity ease-out 1s;
 animation: .05s ease-in-out 0s 4 alternate req;
  
  }

 

 input:-webkit-autofill,
 input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
 input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
 input:-webkit-autofill:active {
   transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
  border:2px solid #f3f3f3;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding-left:13px;
  
 }


 div.button-set {
   display: inline-flex;
 }
 

 div.button-set>label {
   position: relative;
   flex: 0 0 auto;
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   margin-left: 15px;
   border-radius: 100px;
   outline: none;
   border: none;
   margin-bottom: 20px;

 }
 

 .checked {
   background: #f3f3f3;
   border-radius: 100px;
 }

 input[type="submit"] {
   font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr-Thin";
   height: 36px;
   width: 160px;
   font-weight: 100;
   font-size: 24px;
   margin-top: 20px;
   margin-left: 10px;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 100px;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  padding:0;
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 9999;
   width: 5px;
 }

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
   display: none;
 }

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   z-index: 9999;
   background-color: transparent;
 }

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
   z-index: 9999;
   z-index: 9999;
   background-color: transparent;
 }

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   z-index: 9999;
   background-color: #d7d7d7;
   border-radius: 3px;
 }

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
   z-index: 9999;
   background-color: #d7d7d7;
 }

 
 
 .invalid {


  width:12px;
 height:12px;
 color: white;
 position:absolute;
 right:15px;
 top: 12px;
  background:tomato;
 border-radius:6px;
 animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate inv;
 }
  .valid {
  width:12px;
 height:12px;
 color: white;
 position:absolute;
 right:15px;
 top: 12px;
 background:#9dc46b;
 border-radius:6px;
 animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite  alternate inv;
 }
.error {
 text-align:right;
 font-size:12px;
 padding-right:20px;
 padding-top:10px;
 color:gray;
 letter-spacing:.05em;
}
 .hide {
  display:none;
  
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/form.css">
  </head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <form novalidate action="" method="post" name="support" id="support" >
  <label class="required"><span id="vs" class="invalid hide"></span><input id="sellection" class="mail sellection" name="f[sel]" vlaue="" placeholder="выбери удобный способ связи ниже...."  required disabled><span id="error1"></span><div id="sellectionreq" class="iconrequired hide">ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНОЕ</div></label>
      <div class="button-set">
        <label title="Почта"><img class="icons" src='/img/icon/social_icon_mail_white.svg'><input class="radio" id="radio" type="radio" name="f[button-set]" value="на почту" style="display:none;"></label>

        <label for="radio1" title="WhatsApp"><img class="icons" src='/img/icon/social_icon_whatsapp_white.svg'><input class="radio" id="radio1" type="radio" name="f[button-set]" value="в WhatsApp" style="display:none;"></label>

        <label for="radio2" title="Telegram"><img class="icons" src='/img/icon/social_icon_telegram_white.svg'><input class="radio" id="radio2" type="radio" name="f[button-set]" value="в Telegram" style="display:none;"></label>

<label for="radio3" title="Viber"><img class="icons" src='/img/icon/social_icon_viber_white.svg'><input class="radio" id="radio3" type="radio" name="f[button-set]" value="в Viber" style="display:none;"></label>
      </div>
   <label class="required"><span id="vn" class="invalid hide"></span>
   <input id="name" class="mail" type="name" name="f[name]" autocomplete= none placeholder="как к тебе обращаться...." value="" pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё]+(\s+[А-Яа-яЁё]+)?" maxlength="15" minlength="2" required><div id="namereq" class="iconrequired hide">ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНОЕ</div></label>
      <label class="required"><span id="vt" class="invalid hide"></span><textarea id="qestions" type="text" placeholder="введи текст своего вопроса...." name="f[message]" value="" pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё]+(\s+[А-Яа-яЁё]+)?" maxlength="4000" minlength="45" required></textarea><div id="textreq" class="iconrequired hide">ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНОЕ</div></label>  
      <input name="f[submit]" type="submit" id="submit" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ" />
    </form>
  <div id="my_message_email"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: проблема не в этом куске кода, а в том, который сюда отправляет post

Comment: @Kirill да я тоже так думаю, но почему тогда без счетчика все нормально работает, не могу разобраться

Comment: Не 12 а скорее всего 1 конкатенируется с 2.

Comment: А также - если `isset($submit)` __`false`__, то зачем слать письмо?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело, естественно, было не в обработчике на стороне сервера,а в криво написанном Jquery вперемешку с JavaScript. Я переписал все сам, на чистом JS и теперь все в рабочем состоянии. Конечно, я понимаю, что код не очень хорош, он грязный и там много лишнего, но все же он работает. Может быть кому-то понадобиться, как пример.

В этой форме я попытался реализовать такие функции как:

На стороне браузера:

- валидация полей формы в браузере в реальном времени;
- дополнительное выделение пустых обязательных полей при отправке;
- отправка формы с помощью `XMLHttpRequest()` *(без перезагрузки страницы)*.
- подключение reCAPTCHAv2

На стороне сервера:

- простая проверка полей формы;
- проверка reCAPTCHA;
- счетчик отправленных форм для формирования заголовка письма по типу: "*Заявка № 384 с сайта example.ru*" (для того чтобы письма не группировались и их было удобно читать);
- отправка данных с формы на почту.

Форма обратной связи:

```js
var forms = document.getElementById('support');
var names = document.getElementById('name');
var validn = document.getElementById('vn');
var iconrequired = document.getElementById('namereq');
var email = document.getElementById('sellection');
var valids = document.getElementById('vs');
var iconrequireds = document.getElementById('sellectionreq');
var text = document.getElementById('qestions');
var validt = document.getElementById('vt');
var iconrequiredt = document.getElementById('textreq');


//ВАЛИДАЦИЯ ПОЛЕЙ ФОРМЫ
document.addEventListener('input', validateform);

function validateform() {

  var x = document.forms["support"]["sellection"].value;

  if (names.validity.valid) {
    validn.className = "valid";
    iconrequired.classList.add("hide");
  }

  if (email.validity.valid && x !== "") {
    valids.className = "valid";
    iconrequireds.classList.add("hide");
  }

  if (text.validity.valid) {
    validt.className = "valid";
    iconrequiredt.classList.add("hide");
  }

  if (names.validity.valid && email.validity.valid && !email.hasAttribute('disabled') && text.validity.valid === true) {

    iconrequiredt.classList.add("hide");
    iconrequireds.classList.add("hide");
    iconrequired.classList.add("hide");

    return true

  } else {

    if (!names.validity.valid) {
      validn.className = "invalid";
      iconrequired.classList.add("hide");

    }

    if (!email.validity.valid) {
      valids.className = "invalid";
      iconrequireds.classList.add("hide");
    }

    if (!text.validity.valid) {
      validt.className = "invalid";
      iconrequiredt.classList.add("hide");
    }

    if (names.validity.valid || email.validity.valid || !email.hasAttribute('disabled') || text.validity.valid === false) {

      iconrequiredt.classList.add("hide");
      iconrequireds.classList.add("hide");
      iconrequired.classList.add("hide");
    }

  }

}


//ВАЛИДАЦИЯ ФОРМЫ
forms.addEventListener('submit', validspace)

function validspace() {

  if (IsNullEmail() && IsNullName() && IsNullText() && validateform() === true) {

    submitFormAjax();
    return false;

  } else {

    IsNullEmail();
    IsNullName();
    IsNullText();
    return false
  }

  return false
}

//ПУСТЫЕ ПОЛЯ
function IsNullEmail() {

  if (email.value.length === 0) {

    iconrequireds.classList.remove("hide");

  } else {

    iconrequireds.classList.add("hide");

    return true
  }

}

function IsNullName() {

  if (names.value.length === 0) {

    iconrequired.classList.remove("hide");


  } else {

    iconrequired.classList.add("hide");

    return true

  }

}

function IsNullText() {

  if (text.value.length === 0) {

    iconrequiredt.classList.remove("hide");

  } else {


    iconrequiredt.classList.add("hide");

    return true

  }
}

//XMLHttpRequest
function submitFormAjax() {

  let captcha = grecaptcha.getResponse();

  if (captcha.length) {

    let xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ?
      new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
        alert(this.responseText);
    }

    let formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('#support'));
    formData.append('g-recaptcha-response', captcha);

    let data = new URLSearchParams(Array.from(formData)).toString();

    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'https://www.archsupport.ru/post-email.php', true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(data);
  }

  document.querySelector('#support').reset();
  grecaptcha.reset();
}

// setATTR'S
Element.prototype.setAttributes = function(attrs) {
  for (var idx in attrs) {
    if ((idx == 'styles' || idx == 'style') && typeof attrs[idx] == 'object') {
      for (var prop in attrs[idx]) {
        this.style[prop] = attrs[idx][prop]
      }
    } else {
      this.setAttribute(idx, attrs[idx]);
    }
  }
};

//CHANGE VALUE
let radioChange = document.querySelectorAll(".radio");

for (var i = 0, len = radioChange.length; i < len; i++) {
  radioChange[i].addEventListener('change', change);
}

function change() {

  let input = document.getElementById("sellection");

  if (document.querySelector("#radio").checked === true) {
    input.removeAttribute('disabled')
    input.setAttributes({
      'type': 'email',
      'placeholder': 'example@yourmail.ru',
      'autocomplete': 'email',
      'maxlength': '35',
      'minlength': '12',
      'pattern': '^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$',
      'value': ""
    });
  } else if (document.querySelector("#radio").checked == false) {

    input.removeAttribute('disabled');
    input.setAttributes({
      'type': 'tel',
      'placeholder': '+7-910-205-46-15',
      'autocomplete': 'tel',
      'maxlength': '36',
      'minlength': '11',
      'pattern': '\\+7\\s?[\\(]{0,1}9[0-9]{2}[\\)]{0,1}\\s?\\d{3}[-]{0,1}\\d{2}[-]{0,1}\\d{2}',
      'value': ""
    });
  }

  input.value = "";
  input.focus();
};


//ICON ONCLICK
function toggleItem(elem) {
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    elem[i].addEventListener("change", function(e) {
      var current = this;
      for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        if (current != elem[i]) {
          elem[i].classList.remove('checked');
        } else if (current.classList.contains('checked') === true) {
          current.classList.remove('checked');
        } else {
          current.classList.add('checked')
        }
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  };
}
toggleItem(document.querySelectorAll('.icons'));
```

```css
@keyframes req {
  0% {
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatex(5px);
  }
}

@keyframes inv {
  0% {
    opacity: .5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100&display=swap');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 100 !important;
  --lighter: #ededed;
  --light: #d6d6d6;
  --dark: #d7d7d7;
  --dark1: gray;
  --black: #343434;
}

form {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

textarea {
  height: 30vh;
  border-radius: 18px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border: 2px solid var(--dark);
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  outline: none;
  resize: none
}

input,
textarea {
  font-size: 18px;
}

 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: var(--dark1);
  font-size: 18px;
}

 ::-moz-placeholder {
  color: var(--dark1);
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* Firefox 19+ */

 :-moz-placeholder {
  color: var(--dark1);
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* Firefox 18- */

 :-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: var(--dark1);
  font-size: 18px;
}

input:not([type="submit"]) {
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 36px;
  border: none;
  background: var(--lighter);
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid var(--dark);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: white;
  padding-left: 13px;
}

.required {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.iconrequired {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 90px;
  height: 14px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 10px;
  background: var(--black);
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity ease-out 1s;
  animation: .05s ease-in-out 0s 4 alternate req;
}

input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
  border: 2px solid #f3f3f3;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 13px;
}

div.button-set {
  display: inline-flex;
}

div.button-set>label {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.checked {
  background: var(--dark);
  border-radius: 100px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  height: 36px;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 0;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 5px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  display: none;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: transparent;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  z-index: 9999;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: transparent;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

.invalid {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 12px;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 6px;
  animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate inv;
}

.valid {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 12px;
  background: #9dc46b;
  border-radius: 6px;
  animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate inv;
}

.error {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: gray;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.g-recaptcha {
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 36px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async defer></script>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="support" onSubmit='return false' novalidate>
  
    <label class="required"><span id="vs" class="invalid hide"></span><input id="sellection" class="mail sellection" name="sel" vlaue="" placeholder="выбери способ связи...."  required disabled><span id="error1"></span><div id="sellectionreq" class="iconrequired hide">ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО</div></label>
    
    <div class="button-set">
    
      <label title="Email" class="icons"><img  src='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=12dgg88tY-Zv9YJSF3GGFKiBoccbcli7b'><input class="radio" id="radio" type="radio" name="button-set" value="на почту" style="display:none;"></label>
      
      <label for="radio1" title="WhatsApp" class="icons"><img src='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1SEtRXe081ekScf3q8RGR-AbCPIj-BfDM'><input class="radio" id="radio1" type="radio" name="button-set" value="в WhatsApp" style="display:none;"></label>
      
      <label for="radio2" title="Telegram" class="icons"><img  src='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1f_qsaD8vSG99IdKvWNm9xWiJ8h1wdjeM'><input class="radio" id="radio2" type="radio" name="button-set" value="в Telegram" style="display:none;"></label>
      
      <label for="radio3" title="Viber" class="icons"><img  src='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1Qq1htnz12ztZ1i5wPYOaXPLTWul_Vj3o'><input class="radio" id="radio3" type="radio" name="button-set" value="в Viber" style="display:none;"></label>
      
    </div>
    
    <label class="required"><span id="vn" class="invalid hide"></span>
    
   <input id="name" class="mail" type="name" name="name" autocomplete= none value="" placeholder="как к тебе обращаться...."  pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё]+(\s+[А-Яа-яЁё]+)?" maxlength="15" minlength="2" required><div id="namereq" class="iconrequired hide">ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО</div></label>
      
    <label class="required"><span id="vt" class="invalid hide"></span><textarea id="qestions" type="text" value="" placeholder="твой вопрос...." name="message"  pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё]+(\s+[А-Яа-яЁё]+)?" maxlength="400" minlength="40" required></textarea><div id="textreq" class="iconrequired hide">ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО</div></label>
    
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ" />
    
  </form>
  <div id="message"></div>
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LceVswUAAAAAA09b8TVrZhKMFKOhxMmdvPWOzQm" data-size="visible">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

PHP:

```php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); //предотвращает ошибку связанную с заголовком CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Origin»

$email = ($_POST['sel']); 
$change = ($_POST['button-set']);
$name = ($_POST['name']);
$question = ($_POST['message']);
$submit = ($_POST['submit']); 

$secret = '6xceVswUAxxxLgcxxzsssE4z1xxUjqDotYhbb'; //проверка reCAPTCHA
$ip         =$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$recaptcha  =$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$google_url ="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
$url        =$google_url."?secret=".$secret."&response=".$recaptcha."&remoteip=".$ip;
$curl       =curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16");
$curlData   =curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$res        =json_decode($curlData, true);

function clean($value = "") { //функция отчистки от лишних символов
    $value = trim($value);
    $value = stripslashes($value);
    $value = strip_tags($value);
    $value = htmlspecialchars($value);

    return $value;
}

$email = clean($email);
$change = clean($change);
$name = clean($name);
$question = clean($question);

function check_length($value = "", $min, $max) {//функция проверки длинны полей формы 
    $result = (mb_strlen($value) < $min || mb_strlen($value) > $max);
    return !$result;
}

if(!empty($email) && !empty($name) && !empty($question)) {

    if(check_length($email, 11, 36) && check_length($name, 2, 15) && check_length($question, 40, 400) && $res['success']) {//проверка длинны полей формы 


$counter_file = 'counter.txt'; //счетчик
clearstatcache();
ignore_user_abort(true); 
$fh = fopen($counter_file, 'r+b');
if ($fh)
{
if (flock($fh, LOCK_EX))
{
$count = fread($fh, filesize($counter_file));
rewind($fh);
$count++;
fwrite($fh, $count);
fflush($fh);
ftruncate($fh, ftell($fh));
flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
} fclose($fh);
} else 
ignore_user_abort(false); 

$to = 'support@archsupport.ru';   //отправка на email
$subject = 'Заявка №' . $count . ' с сайта archsupport.ru'; 
$message = 'Имя: ' . $name . "\r\n" . 'Контакты: ' . $email . "\r\n" . 'Написать ' . $change . "\r\n" . 'Вопрос: ' . $question  ; 
$headers = 'From: zergg52@gmail.com ' . "\r\n";
$subject = preg_replace("/(\r\n)|(\r)|(\n)/", "", $subject);
$subject = preg_replace("/(\t)/", " ", $subject);
$subject = '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=';
@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo 'сообщение отправлено!';

    } else { 
        echo "форма не была отправлена введенные данные некорректны";
    }
} else { 
    echo "форма не была отправлена заполните пустые поля";
}

?>
```